# Angular event only meant to trigger once triggering multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angularjs-scope, unbind

I have an event that I only want to handle a single time. Based on my understanding of [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2480-unbinding-watch-listeners-in-angularjs.htm) and [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2723-unbinding-scope-on-event-handlers-in-angularjs.htm) blog, having the following style should ensure this behavior:

```
var unbind = $scope.$on(event, function(){
    //do stuff
    unbind();
}
```

But when I put a breakpoint in this code I can see its being called multiple times.

How can I ensure that the code is run once and only once?

Comment: I would just set a flag and use `$scope.$on('$destroy'...` to do cleanup. Where are you using this? And what does `unbind()` do?

Comment: @charlietfl `$scope.$on` as well as `$scope.$watch` return an unbinding function that, when called, ends the listener. I figured out my issue though - the `unbind()` call needs to be the first line due to events being async.

Comment: OK..didn't know that. Must have been added into api along the way because you used to not be able to unbind

Comment: What kind of event is it? And how is it being triggered?

Comment: @PrashantPalikhe Its an Angular `emit`, and I've already gotten my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the asynchronous nature of events, the `unbind()` call needs to be called first, not last, to prevent multiple simultaneous events.

```
var unbind = $scope.$on(event, function(){
    unbind();//first, not last
    //do stuff
}
```